# Manipulating rules

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule

I tried searching in the docs in "Transformation Rules and Definitions", however there wasn't anything of help.

So imagine I have these two rules:

```
{x -> 2, y -> 3} 
{x -> 3, y -> 5}
```

I want to do the following:
I want to multiply the second set of rules by e.g. `I`:
so something like this should come out:

```
{x -> I 3, y -> I 5}
```

and then I want to 'add them together':

```
{x-> 2+3I, y-> 3+5I}
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Context: These are the BestFitParameters from a model of the Re and Im part of data sets. So I essentially have the Im and Re part of my parameters separetely and I want to add them together.

(No, I do not need the parameters to reinsert into the model, this can of course be done naturally with `Normal` and the two nonlinearfits.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = {x -> 2, y -> 3};
b = {x -> 3, y -> 5};

<|a|> + <|b|> I // Normal
```

{x -> 2 + 3 I, y -> 3 + 5 I}

`<||>` is a short form for `Association`

Answer (score 9):

```
{a, b} = {{x -> 2, y -> 3}, {x -> 3, y -> 5}};

Normal @ Merge[Apply @ Complex] @ {a, b}
```

> ```
> {x -> 2 + 3  I, y -> 3 + 5  I}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is a naive solution:

```
Thread[{x, y} -> 
  Map[Times[I, Values[#]] &, {x -> 2, y -> 3}] + 
   Values[{x -> 3, y -> 5}]]
```

Any improvements are welcomed.

Comment: `Thread[{x, y} -> Complex @@@ Transpose[{Values@r1, Values@r2}]]` where `r1` and `r2` are the rules

Answer (score 4):

This is just for fun and to try to get to 10 different ways for doing the same thing in Mathematica !

```
rules = {{x -> 2, y -> 3}, {x -> 3, y -> 5}};
rules = rules /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Sequence @@ {a, b};
rules[[2, {2, 4}]]*I + rules[[1, {2, 4}]];
MapThread[Rule[#1, #2] &, {{x, y} , %}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
MapThread[Sequence[First@#1->Last@#1 + Last@#2 I]&,{{x -> 2, y -> 3}, {x -> 3, y -> 5}}]

(* {x->2+3 I,y->3+5 I} *)
```

**Alternatively**

```
{Replace[{x -> 3, y -> 5}, (a_ -> b_):> (a -> b I),1],{x -> 2,
   y -> 3}}//Merge[Total]//Normal

(* {x -> 2 + 3 I, y -> 3 + 5 I *)
```